# unable to use insert select command

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, primary-key

I am not able to insert two columns from 2 different tables  into a new table. Both the columns are primary keys and are referenced as foreign keys in the structure of the new table.[they are not matching with each , they are being inserted one top of each other in adjacent tables. I want it to be insert alongside each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAcnw.png)

I want them inserted side by side like a normal table. Could anyone please give me a sample code or atleast explain how to do it right?

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Please provide more information about these three tables. Why they have to be alongside each other since they are not matching? Is order important? Do they have the same number of rows? Please give more informations what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To combine two result sets into one, use `UNION` / `UNION ALL`:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  idA varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (idA)
);
INSERT INTO A (idA) VALUES
  ('AAAAA'),
  ('BBB'),
  ('CCCC'),
  ('DD')
;

CREATE TABLE B (
  idB int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idB)
);
INSERT INTO B (idB) VALUES
  (1),
  (2),
  (3)
;

CREATE TABLE C (
  idA varchar(10),
  idB int(6) unsigned,
  foreign key B_idA (idA) references A(idA),
  foreign key B_idB (idB) references B(idB)
);

insert into C(idA, idB)
  select idA, null from A
  union all
  select null, idB from B
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fba0b0/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.